# Cannot clone a git repository and have to create a repository locally first and to configure its local remote setting

Tags: git, permission-denied, git-clone, git-remote

My `~/.ssh` contains two keypairs:

- `id_rsa_foo`&`id_rsa_foo.pub`

  - for user `foousername` on GitHub (`github.com`)
- `id_rsa_bar`&`id_rsa_bar.pub`

  - for user `barusername` on GitHub (`github.com`)
  - for user `barusername` on my server (`indefero.myserver.com`)

The `~/.ssh/config` "knows" the keyfiles:

```
#github.com-foousername account
Host github.com-foousername
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_foo

#github.com-barusername account
Host github.com-barusername
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bar

#indefero.myserver.com-foousername account
Host indefero.myserver.com-foousername
    HostName indefero.myserver.com
    User foousername
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bar
```

The `~/.ssh/known_hosts` "knows" the server:

```
github.com,207.97.227.239 ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...AaQ==
204.232.175.90 ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...AaQ==
indefero.myserver.com,111.222.333.444 ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...Ytw==
```

Now when I'm trying to clone from GitHub, an error ocurres: `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

```
user@machine ~/Desktop/test
$ git clone git@github.com:foousername/project1.git
Cloning into 'foousername'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

But when I create a repository on my local machine first and set the local/project `config` up:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com-foousername:foousername/project1.git
```

I can `pull`/`push`. (This way works for the GitHub repos, the myserver ropos don't want even so and require a password: `indefero@indefero.it-and-t.com's password:`. But might be another problem.)

How can I change this behaviour, in order to clone repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your `~/.ssh/config` correctly, but you are not using the correct host in your `git clone` command. Use the hostname that you have set in your config file to use the corresponding key:

```
# Use your default key
git clone git@github.com:foousername/project1.git

# Use the ~/.ssh/id_rsa_foo key
git clone git@github.com-foousername:foousername/project1.git

# Use the ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bar key
git clone git@github.com-barusername:barusername/project1.git
```

Comment: Yes, sure, hostname by cloning must correspond to the alias in the config file! Now it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: I noticed, that part of the path after the `HostName` is for GitHub and for my server a bit different. On GitHub I additionally need my username. I have an idea, why it's so. But what is the technical cause?

Comment: The address of a git remote just tells git where to find the repo. A remote address could be a local file path: `~/repos/project1.git`, a web address: `http://repo.org/project1.git`, or a SSH address: `git@github.com:foousername/project1.git`. The SSH address tells git to SSH to `github.com`, log in as the `git` user, and look for the repository at the path `foousername/project1.git`. If your repo on the `indefero` server does not live at `~foousername/foousername/project1.git`, you will have to specify a different path, what ever that may be.